# How to relate raw scores on five-point Likert to three conceptual categories?

Tags: likert, scales, weighted-mean

My thesis is on employee productivity and I had a questionnaire which consists of a five-point Likert scale (5-strongly agree, 4-agree, 3-agree, 2-disagree, and 1-strongly disagree). On the other hand, I had a conceptual Framework of a 3 point scale (Highly Productive, Productive and Not Productive).

**Is there any standard way to identify whether my respondents are highly productive, productive or not?**

Comment: I think you have an error in your description of the Likert scale, as you have 4 and 3 being identical.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you have data on the productivity of the respondents? If so, you can use it. If not, how could you possibly do this?

Answer (score 3):

Many psychological tests convert numeric raw scores into categories. For example, Wikipedia mentions cut-offs for the Beck Depression Inventory:

> - 0–9: indicates minimal depression
> - 10–18: indicates mild depression
> - 19–29: indicates moderate depression
> - 30–63: indicates severe  depression.

Or for example the BMI define various cut-offs (e.g., Cole et al, 2007).

In general, you lose information by collapsing categories or using cut-offs. Psychological reality tends to be more continuous. That said, categories do have heuristic value as decision aides.

**A few options** for converting scores to a collapsed set of categories

- Use the logical definition of the scale points: For example, you might use "strongly agree" as highly productive, "agree" as productive, and the other categories as "not productive". This is a simple approach that uses the scale anchor points to define the meaning of the categories.
- Use expert judgements: You can ask a set of experts to evaluate where they thinlk the cut-offs between categories should be. These can then be synthesised. This approach is often used to define acceptable standards for various tests.
- Use normative information: You could use information about the normative spread of the variable and an assumption about the prevalence of the phenomena to define cut-offs.
- Use prediction of external criterion: If the thing has objective existence, or if there are things related to it, you could use predictive models of this external criterion to define the categories.

#### References

- Cole, T. J., Flegal, K. M., Nicholls, D., & Jackson, A. A. (2007). Body mass index cut offs to define thinness in children and adolescents: international survey. Bmj, 335(7612), 194. [FULL TEXT](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1934447/)